# React Typescript, Type '' is not assignable to type 'null'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the start of s simple todo app in with React and typescript

I am creating a context but getting an error in the value of the content provider

```
<TodoContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</TodoContext.Provider>
```

for the value I get the error

```
Type '{ todoList: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'null'.
```

What does error mean and how can i fix this typescript error

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState, ReactChildren, ReactChild } from "react";

interface AuxProps {
    children: ReactChild | ReactChildren;
  }

const TodoContext = createContext(null)

const intialTodo = ['Learn Context']

const TodoProvider = ({children}:AuxProps) => {

    const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState<string[]>(intialTodo)

    const contextValue = {
        todoList
    }

    return(
        <TodoContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</TodoContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useTodoContext = () => useContext(TodoContext)

export default TodoProvider
```

Answer (score 8):

Because you are sending just null.
but context needs null with type
here like that

```js
const TodoContext = createContext(null as any)
render{
 const photosObject = this.context as any
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you assigning null to string array?

```js
const TodoContext = createContext([])
```

does it work for your case?

Comment: I need to assign something so I was trying null, with the empty array I get `Type '{ todoList: string[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'never[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.`

Comment: my apologies, I never worked with react context and took a few minutes to learn and prepared this forked sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-typescript-forked-sn2hmi? please let me know if it doesn't help, then we can try it again